# Erro ao atualizar mysql server no linux Mint

Tags: mysql, linux

Tenho uma maquina com **Linux Mint** que uso como meu servidor de desenvolvimento, que está funcionando normalmente, porem, ao realizar um update (`apt-get upgrade`) dos pacotes instalados, o **mysql server** gera um erro, e após isso o serviço cai e não volta, sendo necessário reiniciar o servidor para que o serviço volte a funcionar, e com isso voltamos o problema de que quando tento atualizar gera o erro novamente.

Abaixo irei mostrar os procedimentos que tentei e o que acontece após eles.

**Versão do MySQL:**

```
└──> # mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

**`apt-get upgrade` após um `update`**

[image: erro após upgrade]
Aqui já começa o erro, após realizar um upgrade parece que ele não consegue levantar o serviço novamente. porem o serviço está rodando, para sair dessa tela é necessário apertar  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  **+**  <kbd>C</kbd> .

Quando tento acessar o MySQL pelo terminal ele gera um erro se socket:

```
┌─[root]@[MediaServer]:~
└──> # mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

A partir daqui só reiniciando o servidor para ter acesso novamente,

Após reiniciar eu tento o comando `mysql_upgrade` porem ele acusa que já está atualizado, porem se eu rodar um o `apt-get upgrade` ele tenta atualizar novamente, mas ele vai acusar que ouve um erro nas instalações e pede para rodar o `sudo dpkg --configure -a` rodando o comando gera o erro novamente:

[image: erro]
Essa marcação é porque ele fica travado nessa linha sendo necessário apertar o  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  **+**  <kbd>C</kbd>  para finalizar.

Basicamente são essas as informações que tenho, e o problema é que meu MySQL está atualizado porem sempre tenta atualizar e acusa erro, Antes de postar aqui procurei (e muito) nos buscadores e testei os exemplos dados, porem nenhum funcionou.

Comment: [Espero que isso possa ajudar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38)

Comment: @CaiodePaulaSilva Obrigado pela dica, mas essa parte do erro do socket só ocorre após eu tentar atualizar o MySQL, se não tentar ele continua funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Veja se você tem outro daemon rodando com `ps aux | grep mysqld`.

Comment: @bfavaretto roda antes ou depois de tentar atualizar ?

Comment: Você já instalou, o problema é pós-instalação. Também tente rodar o mysql_upgrade manualmente.

Comment: @bfavaretto meu MySQL está rodando normalmente, o problema só ocorre quando eu tento atualizar ele, e sim rodei o `mysql_upgrade --force`, sem o force ele nem roda, porque ja diz que esta atualizado.